# Combining tables based on elements from one of the columns

Tags: r, merge, datatables

This is a bit hard to explain so I'll show an example below, but I basically have two tables  and I want to create a new table with a new column by matching what's in the rows of another table. I also want to note that these tables are very large (10,000+ rows).Is there a way to do this in R?

Let's say that these are the tables that I have

```
Table 1-sample
obs      code   genSym   
14       E444     5     
28       3330     6        
33       7555     9      
35       E777     10     

Table 2-description
row_id  code   type   
1       E444    INS             
3       7555    MMS      
5       5679    SMO 
6       A678    LLX 
7       A900    IRR
8       3330    DEL
9       4545    SLL  
10      E777    FOO
```

and I want it to look like this

```
obs      code   genSym  type 
14       E444     5      INS
28       3330     6      DEL  
33       7555     9      MMS
35       E777     10     FOO
```

My first table is my sample table and my second table is my description table that has all of the descriptions of what the codes mean. I want to match the "type" in my first table based on the codes in the first table. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a left join, which can be accomplished [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right). This is a way to do it using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

table_1 = tibble(
  obs = c(14, 28, 33, 35),
  code = c("E444", "3330", "7555", "E777"),
  genSym = c(5, 6, 9, 10)
)

table_2 = tibble(
  code = c("E444", "7555", "5679", "A678", "A900", "3330", "4545", "E777"),
  type =c("INS", "MMS", "SMO", "LLX", "IRR", "DEL", "SLL", "FOO")
)

table_1 %>% left_join(table_2)
Joining, by = "code"
# A tibble: 4 x 4
    obs code  genSym type 
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1    14 E444       5 INS  
2    28 3330       6 DEL  
3    33 7555       9 MMS  
4    35 E777      10 FOO
```